# In Dropbox API SDK, ListFolderAsync() method doesn't return the files inside the shared folder?

Tags: api, sdk, dropbox

I want to get the parent_shared_folder_id of the file that is in shared folder. I am using Dropbox dotnet SDK to get list of files/folders.

var list = await client.Files.ListFolderAsync(string.Empty, true);

But here I don't get the files list inside shared folder. Is there any other method that retries these details?

Comment: `ListFolder` should return files in shared folders too. Does your [`ListFolderResult`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/T_Dropbox_Api_Files_ListFolderResult.htm) have `HasMore` set to `true` though? If so, you need to use `ListFolderContinue` to get the rest of the results.

Comment: Thanks Greg, yes the HasMore value is true in the results and also have the cursor value. Based on ListFolderContinue method I was able to get the next set of files.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using ListFolderAsync method, we get Cursor value that needs to provided as input to ListFolderContinueAsync method to fetch the next set of files/folders.

list = await client.Files.ListFolderContinueAsync(list.Cursor);

These results also include files from shared folder.

Thanks a lot Greg for your inputs, that helped me solve my issue.

Comment: How come this is accepted as correct answer? This is not working to get sub folder contents of a "SHARED" folder. When I call ListFolderAsync it is not accepting recursive flag and throwing error as "Recursive list folder is not supported for shared link". So all first level folder/files are returned by the ListFolderAsync and then ListFolderContinueAsync is not returning anything.